# Problem with simple regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have strings like : `{$foo.bar}` and `{$foo.bar.anything}`
WHERE : `foo AND bar AND anything === alphanumeric`
i want to match the above 2 strings in `PHP` via `preg_match(regular expression)` except those without any dot `for example : {$foo}`
Your help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/{\$[\da-z]+(?:\.[\da-z]+)+}/i
```

matches

```
{$foo.bar}
{$foo.Bar.anything}
{$foo.bar.anything1.anything2.anything3}
{$foo.bar.anything.a.b.c}
```

does not match

```
{$foo}
{$foo.}
{$foo bar}
{$foo.bar anything}
{$foo.bar......anything..}
{$foo.bar.anything.}
{$foo.bar.anything.a.b.c..}
```

Adopted [Joe’s PCRE case-insensitive modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379348/problem-with-simple-regular-expression/7379368#7379368) to shorten it a bit.

Special thanks to sln for keeping me on my toes until it’s perfect. :)

Comment: Matches at least `{$foo.}` and `{$foo}`.

Comment: @Tim Cooper: Rolled back, because you messed it up, double backslashes "\\" will match a backslash "\".

Comment: @sln: Thanks for catching that. I think I fixed it.

Comment: @Herbert: Getting closer, it still matches `{$foo.bar.anything.}`

Comment: @sln: Wow, you're persistent. :D. With this latest improvement, the regex is actually a few characters _shorter_. Nice! :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming php regex is the same as perl

```
^\w+\.[\.\w]+$
```

That means starting with one or more alphanumeric, followed by a `.`, followed by a number of alphanumerics or `.`. The `$` means all the way to the end of the string.

If it cannot end with a `.` then

```
^\w+\.[\.\w]+\w$
```

If `..` is not allowed It gets tricker as not ell regex engines handle specifying repetitions of multi char sub expressions. But if your's does I think its something like

```
^\w+(\.\w+)+$
```

That means starting with one or more alphanumeric, followed one or more repetions of by a `.` followed one or more alphanumerics. The `$` means all the way to the end of the string.

Comment: `\w` matches letters, digits, and underscores.

Comment: PHP regex is the same as Perl (when you use preg_match). The "p" is for PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression).

Comment: @Sodved: I think you want `[^\W_]+(?:\.[^\W_]+)+` to mitigate underscores. Also, its unclear if `^$` anchors are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `preg_match_all` rather than `preg_match` - it gets all matches, as the name suggests, rather than just the first one.

As for the regex you want, something like this should work

```
/\{\$[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z0-9\.]+)+\}/i
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/(\{\$[a-z]+\.([a-z][a-z.])*[a-z]+\})/
```

So you first match foo and a dot `{$foo.`, then optionally any characters and dots `{$foo.bar.`, and finally another string of characters. `{$foo.bar.anything}`

Comment: The unescaped period in the middle parentheses will match any character

Comment: @Joe: Nope, it's OK, inside a character class it will match dot.

Comment: Mm, didn't know that. I do know for sure that the unescaped $ at the start is trying to match end-of-string though :P

Comment: @Joe: Definitely that dollar sign must be escaped! :)

Comment: @Wulf: Why go through all the duplicity (and backtracking)? Can't you just reduce it to `/(\{\$[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)+\})/` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
\{\$[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+\.?[A-Za-z0-9]*\}
```

Comment: Worth noting this will only match string.substring.subsubstring, and if there are any string with more than 2 periods in the (1.2.3.4) then it won't match

Comment: @Joe: Yes, that's right. It seems like that's what the OP is after, but maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
\{\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+\}
```

First match `{$`. Then match any alphanumeric string. Then match any alphanumeric strings beginning with `.`. Then match `}`.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution to the problem, with some alternatives depending on what you exactly want to extract.

1. Extracts just the whole `{$aaa.bbb[.ccc[.ddd ...]]}` thing, provided that it contains at least one dot
2. Extracts the content from the `{$aaa.bbb}` thing (eg. `aaa.bbb`)
3. Consider only tags composed by two or three components (ignore `{$aaa}` or `{$aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd}`).

Code:

```
<?php

$subject = '{$foo.bar} {$foo.bar.baz} {$foo} {$another-foo.bar} {$foo.bar.baz.boh}';

print "Matching the whole string\n";
preg_match_all(
   '/{\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+}/',
   $subject, $m);
print var_export($m) ."\n\n";

print "Matching only the content\n";
preg_match_all(
   '/{\$([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+)}/',
   $subject, $m);
print var_export($m) ."\n\n";

print "Matching for strings containing only 1 or two dots\n";
preg_match_all(
   '/{\$([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+){1,2})}/',
   $subject, $m);
print var_export($m) ."\n\n";
```